# Archive issue with framework created in swift

Tags: objective-c

I created framework in swift and integrated in project. It is giving the error on archive

myFramework.framework/myFramework' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have created some framework in objective c, bit code is disabled with those framework as well. Objective c frameworks are working fine but swifts are not working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your *app target* is configured to use bitcode. Therefore the *framework* must be configured to use bitcode.

As the error message says, you must make them match. You can *either* get a copy of the library/framework that *does* use bitcode, or you must turn bitcode *off* in your app target.